# NavigationExperimental vs React-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm new to React Native (coming from web React), and I'm figuring out how navigation works with React Native.

My first step was to check Facebook's guide about navigation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html. It shows me three solutions: Navigator, NavigatorIOS and NavigationExperimental. The 2nd one is unmaintained, the 1st one is stateful. So I went along with the NavigationExperimental one, which was redux-like and pretty easy to play with.

I then had a look on Google, and found [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux). I read their doc, the mini-tutorial looked really simple, the syntax seemed more familiar to web devs like me, but I don't get the underlying difference between this and NavigationExperimental. Is react-native-router-flux something on top of NavigationExperimental?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** The best router to use now is [React Navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation), which is an extension of the ExNavigation project mentioned below.

Yes, `react-native-router-flux` is built off of a fork from a long time ago but has different functionality now. Last I checked, it still didn't support native animations (which the core libraries now support).

If you're starting a new project, I would suggest you use [ExNavigation](https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation), which members of the core team have said is the most similar to what the next core version of the router will look like.

On January 31st of 2017 (most likely) the core team is releasing a more [full-featured navigator](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Roadmap#core-libraries) that will replace Navigation, NavigationExperimental, and ExNavigation.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-router-flux has issue while you use push to navigation for multiple time multiple same screen will be opened.I solved that issue by calling the this.props.navigation.navigate('router key').
**I would like to suggest you not to use react-native-router-flux.**